# Dividing vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have a vector of objects containing information on trades.  I want to write a function that will return either a vector of the "BUY" trades or a vector of the "SELL" trades?

How do I divide a vector of objects into two vectors?

**EDIT**
I want to do something along these lines:

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> OrderBook::get_aggregated_order_book(SellBuyType which_side) const
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> ret;

    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::iterator i = v_OrderInfo.begin();
        for (; i != v_OrderInfo.end(); ++i)
            ((*i).get_SB_type()==BUY ? v_BuyOrders : v_SellOrders).push_back(i);


    if(which_side==SELL){
        ret = v_SellOrders;
    }
    else{
        ret = v_BuyOrders;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If this is vector<someObject> then use field that define this object as one of those and just add it to another vector. In the end return new created vector.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::partition_copy()`:

```
std::vector<Trade> buy, sell;
std::partition_copy(trades.begin(), trades.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(buy), std::back_inserter(sell),
                    [](Trade const& trade){ return trade.is_buy_side(); });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but my compiler doesn't support C++11

Comment: Well, you can simply replace the lambda with a suitable predicate instead! After all, lambda functions are just a convenience approach to write a corresponding class with a function call operator. ... and everything else is part of C++03. You might get away using `std::mem_fun_ref()`, too, depending on how your predicate works.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate through each element and push_back to one of other two vectors based on a condition. Here's one way (of many):

```
vector<Trade> vec;
vector<Trade> buy;
vector<Trade> sell;

for (const Trade& t : vec)
    (some_condition ? buy : sell).push_back(t);
```

Comment: What do you mean by original?

Comment: @RuthO'Brien That was a typo. Fixed.